# Joining table on previous month with Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to join a table based on the previous month but after several failed attempts I'm not sure how to solve this.

I have a larger query but the join section is pretty simple, my first attempt was to do something like this:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT user_id, coalesce(COUNT(*),0) as count_m,mth
 FROM table_name
 GROUP BY user_id,mth
) M
ON MONTH(main_table.local_date) -1 = M.mth
AND M.user_id = main_table.user_id
```

But of course if you have a date in January and subtract 1 then you get 0, not 12.

The next attempt was to do something with Hive's datesub function:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT user_id, coalesce(COUNT(*),0) as count_m,mth
 FROM table_name
 GROUP BY user_id,mth
) M
ON MONTH(date_sub(main_table.local_date,31)) = M.mth
AND M.user_id = main_table.user_id
```

But again the problem is obvious - not every month has 31 days so you end up with problems for some dates where the previous month is not correctly matched (although at least this solves the January - December problem from the previous approach.

I also tried to use a CASE approach in the ON command, to handle the Jan-Dec problem, before realizing that Hive would only accept equi-joins.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtract the number of days in the month from the date and extract the month.  See code below:

```
ON MONTH(date_sub(main_table.local_date,day(main_table.local_date))) = M.mth
```

Comment: A nice, simple solution - I wish I'd seen it. Thanks!